# Sublime Text 2: Different language highlighting based on context? (a la Webstorm)

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2, webstorm

I was watching some videos on [Egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io) about AngularJS. The creator of the videos uses Webstorm (and, I believe, works for them). One feature I noticed is that he can set different syntax highlighting within different scopes or quotation marks. So, in code like the following (from an AngularJS directive)

```
return {
    template: '<div>something</div>',
    //         ^^^ these guys ^^^
}
```

...he can get the inside of the quotation marks to highlight as HTML.

I use *Sublime Text 2*, and am fairly wedded to it. Is there an existing feature/plugin for Sublime that could handle a case like this? If not, is something like this technically possible using the Sublime Text 2 API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's built in, but it's certainly possible. I've been doing some work with graphviz and wanted to do something similar. Labels can be generated with html like syntax. Anyways, I played around with the `.tmLanguage` file and added a new pattern to match the context where html like entries were valid (I look for `label = <`). The patterns I used for the captures aren't that good, but it works for fine for me. This give me the following, which I think is similar to what you are looking for.

[image: Demo]

I don't know anything about AngularJS, so I can't help you with anything specific to that, but it is certainly possible. Note that in the image below, the last `<table></table>` are just to show that highlighting doesn't occur there.

Edit:

Forgot to include this in the original post, but here is my updated tmLangauage file. That first pattern is what I added([link](https://gist.github.com/skuroda/5173451#file-gistfile1-json-L11)). I used [PlistJsonConverter](https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter) to go from JSON to plist, then saved the file as `.tmLanguage`. Hope this helps.

Comment: did this file overrule the default `DOT.thLanguage`, or does this extend it (somehow).

Comment: @RyanB I ignored the built in graphviz package, so it uses my own.

Answer (score 0):

@skuroda is right, I implemented @skuroda's code with an additional plugin to easily edit HTML within an AngularJS directive JS file. The result is HTML syntax highlighting within a directive JS file and additional functionality to remove string related delimiters  while editing templates....  [Sublime AngularJS HTML Template Plugin](https://github.com/gitsome/sublime_angular_templates)