# Use one language definition inside another?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm writing a language definition for sublime text for the Kinetic Rule Language. In KRL, there are some places where you can write HTML or Javascript, so I want to let the Javascript and HTML language definitions take over for these blocks.

I thought it would be as simple as just specifying `text.html` or `source.js` for the scope name, but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone shed some light on the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the regions in which HTML or javascript will be defined, you can define a start and end regular expressions, and include the language. It's described a little more in [Sublime Text 2: Different language highlighting based on context? (a la Webstorm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436858/sublime-text-2-different-language-highlighting-based-on-context-a-la-webstorm/15441612#15441612).

If instead you want to include it globally (for instance if you were simply extending the language), you can add the following as an entry under "patterns".

```
<dict>
    <key>include</key>
    <string>source.js</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>include</key>
    <string>text.html</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: You're right, it needs to be `include`'d, not used as the scope name. Thanks!