# Sublime text multiple language syntax highlight?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there something like multiple language highlight syntax in Sublime Text? For example my code might look like this:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
   {% if task == 'archimed_spiral' %}
       <p> 
           $\frac{2}{3}$
       </p>

   {% elif task == 'gcd' %}
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Which is LaTeX inside html inside Jinja2. It gets pretty hard to read it properly.
**Note**
I know about Jinja2 package for Sublime, so it does highlight Jinja2 + html. Maybe I am just asking for too much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can embed syntax highlighting. You basically define a start and end pattern, then include an existing scope. See [Sublime Text 2: Different language highlighting based on context? (a la Webstorm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436858/sublime-text-2-different-language-highlighting-based-on-context-a-la-webstorm/15441612#15441612).