# Is There a Way to Set Syntax Scope in Sublime Text Partway Through a File?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to manually specify a scope for a section of a file within Sublime Text?

For example, consider a file with the Scope **HTML (Twig)**, set through the file's extension. Partway through the file, there are lines in a syntax different from the main file's syntax. I would like to use some sort of a comment to start a new, temporary scope for that section of the file.

**An Example**

*The file is called page.html.twig*

```
<div>
    <p>Fluffy Bunnies</p>
</div>

{% set awesomeJs %}
    $( document ).ready( function ( ) {
        // Do some fancy transition.
    });
{% endset %}
{% includeJs awesomeJs %}
```

I would love to find a way to specify the text between the `set` and `endset` as JavaScript.

The tricky part here, is that text between a `set` and an `endset` is not always JavaScript. It can be any type of text.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871014/sublime-text-multiple-language-syntax-highlight