# syntax highlighting for JSX not working in sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx, babeljs

I am using sublime text for react.js development and everything is fine but the syntax highlighting for the inline code inside html files as shown in line number 18.

[image]

note that syntax highlighting works fine within example.js that was wired up in line number 16

Comment: It doesn't work because in sublime your syntax highlighting is set to `HTML`. See bottom right corner in you sublime. In your js file it would have been set to `jsx` and that's why it worked correctly there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because in sublime your syntax highlighting is set to `HTML`. See bottom right corner in you sublime. In your `js` file it would have been set to `jsx` and that's why it worked correctly there. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436858/sublime-text-2-different-language-highlighting-based-on-context-a-la-webstorm/15441612#15441612)** answer on Stackoverflow explains how you can achieve it in **Sublime Text 2**.

You can also visit and look at Sublime text 3 documentation for syntax **[here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)**

I suppose these will help you and I could explain the problem to you.

Answer (score 15):

You need to select Javascript (Babel) for the language in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Comment: Great, worked for me. I had a great mess with jsx. but should I do this for every single file in my project? No chance to make it work automatically?

Comment: You have to install the Package `babel` for this to work

Comment: You can do automatically when you pick the right bottom corner and then choose "Open all with current extension as".