# SublimeText3: Multiple syntax on a single file

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, markdown, sublimetext

Is there a way to have multiple syntaxes on a single file? I'm working with Markdown files that have LaTeX on them, that I later convert with `pandoc`. That's why I would like to use my LaTeX plugin of choice and it's snippets with syntax highlighting of both filetypes.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you are trying to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436858/sublime-text-2-different-language-highlighting-based-on-context-a-la-webstorm/15441612#15441612

Comment: You need to write you own syntax definition, which includes definitions from both syntax files and combines them such they cooperate with each other.