# multiple syntax highlighting in sublimetext 3 with .sublime-syntax file type

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, zk, zscript

I'm using zk framework and I need to do a sublime-syntax file that highlights in XML syntax, but in the zscript snippet uses java syntax highlighting and in style context uses CSS syntax. 
This is an example of zk code:

```
<zk>
    <style>
        .myClass{
            width=300px;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="panel1" class="myClass" visible="true" >   
        <hlayout width="100px">
            <image id="icon1" src="/Desktop/image1.png" width="32px"></image>   
            <image id="icon2" src="/Desktop/image1.png" width="50px"></image>   
        </hlayout>
    </div>  

    <zscript><![CDATA[
        try{
            if (panel1.isVisible()) {
                //do something
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            //catch exception
        }
    ]]></zscript>
</zk>
```

I saw that some things have been changed recently and the current solutions that are on-line are not very clear, for example at [this link](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) I found the following note:

> As of Sublime Text Build 3084, a new syntax definition format has been
>   added, with the .sublime-syntax extension.
>
> It is highly encouraged to be used in favor of the legacy format
>   described in this document, unless compatibility with older versions
>   is desired.
>
> Documentation is available here:
>   http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html

So I need something like a tutorial on how to build a new multiple syntax file with SublimeText3.

Comment: I guess you know that already, but just to be sure: [Official plugin](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Studio_Essentials/Features_of_ZK_Studio/ZUL_Editor#Syntax_Coloring) supports this in Eclipse. Furthermore, a Google search for "sublime multiple syntax highlighting" showed up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436858/sublime-text-2-different-language-highlighting-based-on-context-a-la-webstorm/15441612#15441612). This might work, as there is the zscript tag you can use as a start and end pattern.

Comment: It's not the same thing, now is changed the way to do it

Comment: However the official Eclipse Plugin is not very well done to me, and in general I don't appreciate Eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok I solved my problem by installing [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`, select `Package Control: Install Package`, type and select `PackageDev` in order to install it), then I've selected: `Tools` -> `Packages` -> `Package Developement` -> `New Syntax Definition`.

Here I wrote this code:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html

name: zul
file_extensions:
 - zul
scope: text.zul

contexts:
  main:
    - match: ""
      push: "Packages/XML/XML.sublime-syntax"
      with_prototype:

        - match: '< *zscript *>'
          push: Packages/Java/Java.sublime-syntax
          with_prototype:
            - match: '(?=</ *zscript *>)'
              pop: true

        - match: '< *script *>'
          push: Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
          with_prototype:
            - match: '(?=</ *script *>)'
              pop: true

        - match: '< *style *>'
          push: Packages/CSS/CSS.sublime-syntax
          with_prototype:
            - match: '(?=</ *style *>)'
              pop: true
```

- `File_extensions` is a list of extensions that uses this syntax,
- `scope` is `source` for programming languages and `text` for markup and everything else.
- The `match` is the regular expression passed to the `push` element.
- `with_prototype` is something like an exception in the syntax highlighting where you can define a snippet with a different syntax for different contexts

This example uses generally the **xml** syntax, between the tag `<zscript> ... </zscript>` uses the **java** syntax highlighting and in the `<style> ... </style>` context uses the **css** syntax.

I saved this file in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` and then I founded this syntax file in my `View` -> `Syntax` -> `User` -> `zul` (the name of the file).